# IntelliJ PitTest plugin has a missing dependency?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, mutation-testing, pitest

I have installed PIT Mutation testing Idea plugin for IntelliJ. I have a small demo project in Java 8, it runs the mutation tests perfectly.

Our larger project, which is still Java 7 consists of a parent with a lot of Maven modules. I'm not sure if the problem lies in the modules or in some other dependency problem, but when I run the plugin on this project it fails with the following error. Google hasn't been very helpful except I'm not the only one, so I was hoping anyone on SO has run into the problem and knows how to fix it.

The error I get after the build (when mutation test should start running) is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: joptsimple.OptionParser.acceptsAll(Ljava/util/List;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljoptsimple/OptionSpecBuilder;
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.OptionsParser.<init>(OptionsParser.java:122)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport.main(MutationCoverageReport.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Thank you for your reply!

Kind regards,

Johan Kragt